# how to read files in multi process, multi threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, multiprocessing

I was successful in reading a file while using multi-process environment using file locking
and in case of multithreaded(singleprocess) i used a queue filled it with file names, opened a thread separately, read from it and then waited till the entire reading was over, after which i used to rename them. In this way i used to read files in multithreaded(in a batch).

Now, i want to read the files in a directory using both multiprocess and multithreads. I tried merging my two approaches but that didn't fare well. log showed a lot of files were showing FileNotFound exception(because their names were changed), some were never read (because thread died), sometimes locks were not released.

```
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     //file filter inner class
     class myfilter implements FileFilter{

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("email[0-9]+$");
                Matcher mat = pat.matcher(pathname.toString());
                if(mat.find()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    myfilter filter = new myfilter();
    File alreadyread[] = new File[5];
    Thread t[] = new Thread[5];
    fileread filer[] = new fileread[5];
    File file[] = directory.listFiles(filter);
    FileChannel filechannel[] = new FileChannel[5];
    FileLock lock[] = new FileLock[5];
    tuple_json = new ArrayList();
    //System.out.println("ayush");
    while(true) {
        //declare a queue
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue filequeue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

        //addfilenames to queue and their renamed file names
        try{
        if(file.length!=0) {
            //System.out.println(file.length);
            for(int i=0;i<5 && i<file.length;i++) {

                System.out.println("acquiring lock on file " + file[i].toString());
                try{
                filechannel[i] = new RandomAccessFile(file[i], "rw").getChannel();
                lock[i] = filechannel[i].tryLock();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    file[i] = null;
                    lock[i] = null;
                    System.out.println("cannot acquire lock");
                }
                if(lock[i]!=null){
                    System.out.println("lock acquired on file " + file[i].toString());
                   filequeue.add(file[i]);
                   alreadyread[i] = new File(file[i].toString() + "read");
                   System.out.println(file[i].toString() + "-----" + times);
                }
                else{

                   System.out.println("else condition of acquiring lock");
                    file[i] = null;
                }
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
            }

        //starting the thread to read the files
        for(int i=0;i<5 && i<file.length && lock[i]!=null && file[i]!=null;i++){
            filer[i] = new fileread(filequeue.toArray()[i].toString());
            t[i] = new Thread(filer[i]);
            System.out.println("starting a thread to read file" + file[i].toString());
            t[i].start();
        }

        //read the text
        for(int i=0;i<5 && i<file.length && lock[i]!=null && file[i]!=null;i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("waiting to read " + file[i].toString() + " to be read completely");
                t[i].join();
                System.out.println(file[i] + " was read completetly");
                //System.out.println(filer[i].getText());

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        //file has been read Now rename the file
        for(int i=0;i<5 && i<file.length && lock[i]!=null && file[i]!=null;i++){
            if(lock[i]!=null){
                System.out.println("renaming file " + file[i].toString());
                file[i].renameTo(alreadyread[i]);
                System.out.println("releasing lock on file  " + file[i].toString());
                lock[i].release();
        }
        }

//rest of the processing
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Fileread class

```
class fileread implements Runnable{
//String loc = "/home/ayusun/workspace/Eclipse/fileread/bin";
String fileloc;
BufferedReader br;
String text = "";
public fileread(String filename) {
    this.fileloc = filename;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileloc));
        System.out.println("started reading file" + fileloc);
        String currline;
        while((( currline = br.readLine())!=null)){
            if(text == "")
                text += currline;
            else
                text += "\n" + currline;
        }

        System.out.println("Read"  + fileloc  + " completely");
        br.close();

    } catch ( IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
}
```

I would like to know, if there is nay other approach that i can adopt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create exclusive access to a file, you cannot use file locking, as on most OSes file locking is advisory, not mandatory.

I'd suggest creating a common lock directory for all your processes; in this lock directory, you would create a **directory** per file you want to lock, right before you open a file.

The big advantage is that directory creation, unlike file creation, is atomic; as such, you can use `Files.createDirectory()` (or File's `.mkdir()` if you still use Java6 but then don't forget to check the return code) to grab a lock on the files you read. If this fails, you know someone else is using the file.

Of course, when you're done with a file, don't forget to remove the lock directory matching this file... (in a `finally` block)

(note: with Java 7 you can use `Files.newBufferedReader()`; there is even `Files.readAllLines()`)

Comment: i guess this method can work, however i would like to know, can this method be still be applied if there are large number of files(large means seriously too many), so i will be creating these many directories and then will be deleting it,how much will be overhead?

Comment: Close to zero; directory creation/deletion is really cheap ;)

Comment: Note that you may want to partition, say "f/file", "a/anotherfile" if you are afraid that your fs may have a limited number of entries per directory; but on the vast majority of filesystems today, you can create millions of them

Comment: And it did worked. Have tried with two different process(single thread each though) but the main problem seems to have been solved.

I was able to read 20000 files(3 lines each :D) within a minute with just two processes. Is the speed good,or is it supposed to be more?

Btw, Thanks! :)

Comment: I knew you wouldn't fail ;) I have been doing synchronization this way for ages and it never failed on me

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process a large number of files using multiple threads, you should probably first distribute the specific files to each thread before it starts.

For example, if you only want to process files whose names start with `email` and are followed by some digits, you could create 10 threads. The first thread would look for files with names starting with `email0`, the second thread could handle `email1`, etc.

This of course would be efficient only if the numbers are evenly distributed.

Another way could be do have the main thread run through and collect all filenames to deal with. It could then divide the files across the number of available threads, and pass each thread an array of those file names.

There could be other ways of dividing the system load which are relevant to your situation.

Comment: Actually it's a code of a daemon. So when ever a process starts, it starts a new daemon.Every daemon calls threads to read the files like you mentioned. And thus conflicts arises.

Comment: In that case, the daemon needs to know which files are already processed, or which files are being handled by other daemons. Maintain this list outside the daemons - could be a file, or a database.